# Remove some Nodes XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt

Based on my few experience in `xslt`, I want your help. 
My Input `XML` looks like:

```
<XML>
 <Style id="12">
 <Drop>ST</Drop>
 <Col Code="277" Description="test" Group="565">
     <EAN en="123" si="XS"/>
 </Col>
 </Style> 
 <Style id="12">
  <Drop>LT</Drop>
  <Col Code="277" Description="test" Group="235">
     <EAN en="123" si="XL"/>
  </Col>
 </Style>
 <Style id="12">
  <Drop>LT</Drop>
  <Col Code="276" Description="test" Group="235">
     <EAN en="123" si="XL"/>
  </Col>
  </Style>
  <Style id="13">
  <Drop>MD</Drop>
  <Col Code="276" Description="test" Group="235">
     <EAN en="123" si="XL"/>
  </Col>  
  </Style> 
</XML>
```

And I would like to make a transformation to get this Output File:

```
<XML>
 <Style id="12">
  <Drop>ST</Drop>
  <Col Code="277" Description="test" Group="565">
     <EAN en="123" si="XS"/>
  </Col>
 </Style>      
 <Style id="12">
  <Drop>LT</Drop>
  <Col Code="276" Description="test" Group="235">
     <EAN en="123" si="XL"/>
  </Col>
 </Style>
 <Style id="13">
  <Drop>MD</Drop>
  <Col Code="276" Description="test" Group="235">
     <EAN en="123" si="XL"/>
  </Col>  
  </Style> 
</XML>
```

The Conditions are:

1. IF DROP="ST" and DROP != (not equal)"ST"  BUT the SAME Style@id and Col@id. We have to get only the nodes of the nodes that Contains DROP="ST"
2. All the Nodes if Col@id and Style@id are different.

Comment: Your conditions are not really clear: there is *something* to do (keep the elements? remove the element?) if `Drop = "ST"` **and** `Drop != "ST"`, which does not make a lot of sense; while the attribute `Style/@id` exists, there is no `Col/@id`; could you clarify when a `Style` element must disappear from the output?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response!. the Element with the Repetition has to be removed if the Condition is true. : DROP="ST" (e.g of Style1) and DROP != (not equal)"ST" (e.g For Style2) with the same  Style@id and Col@id. then the Style 2 must disappear. if we have different col@id od. Col@id then nothing must be removed. THANKS a lot

Comment: Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This should produce the output you need:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="StyleCol" match="//Style" use="concat(@id, Col/@Code)"/>

    <!-- identity transformation -->
    <xsl:template match="* | @* | text()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="* | @* | text()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- don't copy "duplicated" Style elements -->
    <xsl:template match="Style[Drop != 'ST' and generate-id(.) != generate-id(key('StyleCol', concat(@id, Col/@Code)))[1]]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It uses an `xsl:key` to map the concatenation of `Syle/@id` and `Style/Col/@code` to `Style` elements, and checks whether each node is the first one associated with that key.